# Why is Chrome blocking my google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created google apps scripts to access a google sheets file. This manipulates it, prints from it and accesses it for searching.  I've created a website to access these scripts but when I use chrome it warns of a security concern and blocks a script when I try to print a file. "This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated  sources."  Looking at verifying the script, but this said if used internally only and less than 5 users, then I shouldn't verify.  Any help?

Comment: What kind of script you created? Is it a web app? Does it include client side code? Add a [mcve].

Comment: Hi Ruben, thanks for the reply. This is a web app with client side code yes.  I managed to figure this one out.  It was tricky because I had two issues  unrelated, but going through the workflow of the app I created I ran into both at the same time.  I went from a HTTPS google script to my http site which had mixed content so this created the shield block.  Once I've accepted the "risk" and followed the link I couldn't come back to my script again to load more content.   This was because I had iframes which was blocked due to security.  I installed plugin breaking frames to fix this.

Comment: please post the solution as amazing answer